# Given a specific column value, merge two columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with the following content (simplified):

[image]

And this is the desired result:

[image]

In short, the first column has hundreds of values and sometimes repeated, for a given value of IDPRODUCTFIRST I want a RESULT column with the given value + the values ​​of IDPRODUCTSECOND.

```
SELECT IDPRODUCTSECOND AS RESULT
FROM [SCIOHIST].[dbo].[RELATIONPRODUCTMATCHES]
WHERE IDPRODUCTFIRST = 228697
```

With the query above, I can only get the values ​​from the second column, how could I add to the result column the given value (e.g. 228697) from the first column?

Comment: `select 228697 as RESULT union all <your query>;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to unpivot and select distinct values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.RESULT
FROM [SCIOHIST].[dbo].[RELATIONPRODUCTMATCHES] RPM CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (IDPRODUCTFIRST), (IDPRODUCTSECOND)) V(RESULT)
WHERE IDPRODUCTFIRST = 228697;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT IDPRODUCTFIRST AS RESULT
FROM [SCIOHIST].[dbo].[RELATIONPRODUCTMATCHES]
--WHERE IDPRODUCTFIRST = 228697
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT IDPRODUCTSECOND AS RESULT
FROM [SCIOHIST].[dbo].[RELATIONPRODUCTMATCHES]
--WHERE IDPRODUCTFIRST = 228697
```

where clauses can exist or not. 
IF you want duplicate value in both column are in your result you can use from "UNION ALL" instead of "UNION".

Comment: Two `distinct` queries and an extra _distinct_ by using `union` rather than `union all`?

Comment: No.You do not need to extra query. Just this two query with union or union all

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Union`

```
; With cteProd 
as
(
    SELECT IDPRODUCTFIRST, IDPRODUCTSECOND 
    FROM [SCIOHIST].[dbo].[RELATIONPRODUCTMATCHES]
)
Select RESULT from
(
    SELECT IDPRODUCTFIRST, IDPRODUCTFIRST AS RESULT
    FROM cteProd
    Union 
    SELECT IDPRODUCTFIRST, IDPRODUCTSECOND AS RESULT
    FROM cteProd
) Q
WHERE IDPRODUCTFIRST = 228697
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f02ca60e5482aa6a59be1f9b1a0967db)

Comment: @HABO, It doesn't seems to be just for 228698, it looks like for any IDPRODUCTFIRST  value. The OP says `column the given value (e.g. 228697)` which is anyhow going to be queried from main table. I put that just to have one filter condition. Or if it is to be done in the beginning, I can use the filtering inside cte.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is UNPIVOT

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([IDPRODUCTFIRST] varchar(50),[IDPRODUCTSECOND] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (228697,228699)
,(228697,228701)

Select Distinct Result
 From  (Select [IDPRODUCTFIRST],[IDPRODUCTSECOND] 
         From  @YourTable 
         Where [IDPRODUCTFIRST] = 228697
       )  a
 Unpivot ( Result for Item in ([IDPRODUCTFIRST],[IDPRODUCTSECOND]) ) unp
```

**Returns**

```
Result
228697
228699
228701
```